# Need to block some URL from robots file

Tags: php, robots.txt

I would like to disallow some URLs in robots file of my website and have some difficulties.

Right now my robots file has the following content:

```
User-agent: *

Allow: /
Disallow: /cgi-bin/

Sitemap: http://seriesgate.tv/sitemap.xml
```

I do not want Google to index the following URLs:

```
http://seriesgate.tv/watch-breakingbad-online/season5/episode8/searchresult/
```

There are 8000 more URLs like this. So a code in robots file that block all this.

AND also I want to disallow search box from robots file so that search pages  are not crawled by Google for example this URL:

```
seriesgate.tv/search/indv_episodes/friends/
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Add `Disallow: /name_of_folder/` to not allow google to crawl into a folder and add  `Disallow: /file_name` to not allow google to crawl a specific file..

Comment: So what should i write in robots file because my site has 400 shows so i have to write something that cover all shows not just the breaking bad or the episode mentioned above. (All shows and their episodes)

Comment: The best way is put the shows in a folder named 'shows' the simply add `Disallow: /shows/` but this will result in changing the links in the codes, which can be done using any code editor(using find and replace option)

Answer (score 0):

First, your robots.txt (as included in your question) is invalid. There must not be a line break after the `User-agent` line.

Second, you don’t need the `Allow` line, as everything is allowed which is not explicitly blocked anyway.

---

If all your 8000 URLs you want to block start with "watch-", you could use:

```
Disallow: /watch-
```

For blocking the search results, you could use:

```
Disallow: /search/
```

Note that you have to check if no others pages, which you don’t want to block, are matched by these `Disallow` values.

So your robots.txt could look like:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /watch-
Disallow: /search/

Sitemap: http://seriesgate.tv/sitemap.xml
```

It would block URLs like:

- `http://seriesgate.tv/watch-`
- `http://seriesgate.tv/watch-me`
- `http://seriesgate.tv/watch-me.html`
- `http://seriesgate.tv/watch-/`
- `http://seriesgate.tv/search/`
- `http://seriesgate.tv/search/some-result`
- `http://seriesgate.tv/search/in-titles/foobar.html`
- …